# Using QGIS processing algorithms in C++

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-processing, c++

There are no instructions for using QGIS processing algorithms in the C ++ programming language but it exists in the Python language.

Is it possible to use QGIS processing algorithms in C ++?

Answer (score 2):

```
QgsApplication::processingRegistry()->addProvider( new QgsNativeAlgorithms( QgsApplication::processingRegistry() ) );

QgsProcessingContext context;
context.setProject(QgsProject::instance());

QVariantMap parameters;
parameters["INPUT"] = input_layer->id();
parameters["OUTPUT"] = QgsProcessing::TEMPORARY_OUTPUT;

auto algorithm = QgsApplication::processingRegistry()->algorithmById("native:dissolve");

QgsProcessingFeedback feedback;
auto result = algorithm->run(parameters, context, &feedback);
auto output_layer = QgsProcessingParameters::parameterAsVectorLayer(algorithm->parameterDefinition("OUTPUT"), result, context );
```

Comment: The above answer seems to be only suitable for native algorithms, and does not support gdal and qgis algorithms. How can I solve it